# templateUrl in Angular doesn't work while just template works

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my templateUrl doesn’t want to work. How can I correctly indicate the route or where i should to put the home.html?

My jsp file:

```
<html ng-app='myShoppingList'ng-controller="myCtrl">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/main.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Product Page</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <a href="#/home">Home</a>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
var app = angular.module('myShoppingList', ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'SpringIntro\src\main\resources\home.html',
            controller: 'myCtrl'
          })
      });

app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
      $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
    }]);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
      console.log('myCtrl');
    })
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to tag this with angularjs instead of angular..

Comment: The URL u have given is wrong. Always use relative URL something like this "../resource/home.html" and also don't use \ use /

Comment: It is not wise to mix versions of `angular.js` and `angular-route.js`.

Comment: Check the network tab of the Developer Console to see if the app is fetching the template correctly.

Comment: Solved. Thank you! I have this protepty "spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp". And i should have indicated the same format jsp.